# Installing homebrew - dangerous permission changes?

Tags: osx, homebrew

I'd like to install homebrew, but when I start it up, I get this message:

```
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
```

Seems harmless enough, but this is a mission-critical server and it'd be pretty bad for anything to stop working suddenly. Inside the folder isn't a lot of programs, but there are a couple of critical things (like our backup application).

Is there any way I can verify that this will be harmless? Or, maybe better yet, **can I change the homebrew default directory** to something else that isn't used for anything right now?

Currently, the permissions of that folder is **root:wheel**

Comment: I can't confirm 100%, but in my decades of experience with UNIX, I would say that is is extremely unlikely that this would matter. All of these directories are intended to be world-readable, root-writable, and sysadmin-maintained. The actual gid attached to them is more a piece of documentation than anything else.

Comment: I'll wait a bit just in case someone has something authoritative to contribute as an answer, but if not then I'll repost that as an answer.

Comment: okay, well, I went with it an all seems good so - I think you were correct

Comment: Something very much like that is the Debian default. But Debian uses 'staff' instead.